# Lucene.NET highlighter plugin highlighting strangely

Tags: lucene.net, lucene-highlighter

I'm trying to add the Lucene.NET Highlighter to my search, however it's doing some really strange highlighting, what am I doing wrong?

Here's the highlighting code:

```
// stuff here to get scoreDocs

var content = doc.GetField("content").StringValue();
// content = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been"

  
var highlighter = new Highlighter(new StrongFormatter(), new HtmlEncoder(), new QueryScorer(query.Rewrite(indexSearcher.GetIndexReader())));
highlighter.SetTextFragmenter(new SimpleFragmenter(100));
var tokenStream = analyzer.TokenStream("content", new StringReader(content));

var bestFragment = highlighter.GetBestFragment(tokenStream, content);
```

Searching for `"lorem"` gives me this bestFragment value:

```
<strong>Lorem</strong> <strong>Ipsum</strong> is <strong>simply</strong> <strong>dummy</strong> <strong>text</strong> of the <strong>printing</strong> and <strong>typesetting</strong> <strong>industry</strong>. <strong>Lorem</strong> <strong>Ipsum</strong> <strong>has</strong> <strong>been</strong>
```

As you can see, its highlighted much more than just `"Lorem"`. Why?

How do I make this behave sensibly?

I'm using a `StandardAnalyzer` and my query looks like `"content:lorem"`

**Edit:** I'm using Lucene.NET 2.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't submitted your implementation of `StrongFormatter` or `HtmlEncoder`, but I would say that your implementation error is in the first one. It needs to check the score of the passed `TokenGroup` to decide if any formatting is needed.

```
public class StrongFormatter : Formatter {
    public String HighlightTerm(String originalText, TokenGroup tokenGroup) {
        var score = tokenGroup.GetTotalScore();
        if (score == 0)
            return originalText;

        return String.Concat("<strong>", originalText, "<strong>");
    }
}
```

However, you're not the first one that wants to wrap matches in a html element. You could just use the `SimpleHTMLFormatter` formatter that comes with Highlighter.Net. And while at it, there's also a `SimpleHTMLEncoder` which probably does what your HtmlEncoder does.

Comment: damn, thats embarrassing! thank you, this has been driving me mad! so obvious!